# How to install custom build AOSP apps in Android phone

Tags: android-source, android-mms

I have build MMS app from AOSP (Build no: LMY48M) using the following command

`make -j8 Mms`

The command produces a Mms.apk file, that I would like to install in my Nexus 5 phone. The phone is rooted and has Android Build number LMY48M installed.

The phone should contain a Mms app installed with the same app Id of my Mms.apk file. I wanted to remove the installed Mms app from the phone as I have root permission. I do not find any Mms application whatsoever. SMS functionality is being provided by Hangouts app.

Moreover, when I tried to install the generated Mms.apk file, it shows permission screen with the install button. Tapping on install button starts the installation process but stops in few seconds with error "App not installed."

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lunch aosp_arm-eng` command is for emulator and won't work for device build,  rather use specific command for the device. For Nexus 5 you need to use command  `lunch aosp_hammerhead-userdebug` (Ref: https://source.android.com/source/running.html#selecting-device-build)

P.S you should download the same branch as of your device build number. For instance, my Nexus 5 device has build number LMY48M, so I should download branch `android-5.1.1_r14`. For more information, https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

Now you can install the Mms.apk file just tapping on it from device. You do not need to uninstall/remove Hangouts.

The Mms application has been replaced in Lillipop by Hangouts app. If you would like to install the Mms app as an internal app then you need to make the following folder structure in your rooted device,

`system/priv-app/Mms/Mms.apk`

and restart the device.

Answer (score 0):

You should try copy paste the apk into system->app instead of installing

Answer (score 0):

You should install the apk using the adb install command:

`adb install -r Mms.apk`

This should install the latest apk and will perform an update of the previous version of the Mms.apk if it is already present.

The tricky part here is if it is already present the new apk must be signed with the same cert as the existing one. I'm not sure if those are public certs or not but it's worth a try.